# Mocha tests don't execute in gitlab runner

Tags: javascript, docker, mocha.js, gitlab, gitlab-ci

When I call

```
"test": "NODE_ENV=test ./node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha --require babel-core/register test/**/*test.js --reporter spec"
```

Locally I get all the tests executed, however if I launch it via Gitlab-runner with docker executor. Only describe block gets executed. **Before** or **it** do not get executed.

Code of test:

```
describe('\'users\' service', () => {
  before(() => getApp().then((data) => {
    app = data;
    console.log('not logged here');
  }).catch(err => console.log(err)));
  console.log('logged here');  
  it('registered the service', () => {
    assert.ok(app.service('users'), 'Registered the service');
    console.log('not logged here');  
  });
  console.log('logged here');  
});
```

Gitlab config:

```
image: node:8.11.2

cache:
  paths:
    - node_modules/

test:
  stage: test
  environment: Test
  script:
    - cd app/myccio
    - npm i -g mocha
    - npm i -g chai
    - yarn install --ignore-engines
    - yarn run test
  coverage:
    '/Statements.*?(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)%/'
```

Error on gitlab-runner does not say anything, just exit code 1.

Comment: Looks like I have the same issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56078252/gitlab-ci-job-succeeds-before-mocha-tests-are-run